# Css Responsivo não funciona corretamente

Tags: css

Estou com um problema onde estou fazendo um display responsivo onde o de desktop está ficando por cima do @MEDIA SCREEN e no celular não está pegando o responsivo.

```
.portfolio-modal .close-modal {
position: absolute;
right: 25px;
width: 180px;
top: 5px;
height: 75px;
background-color: transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
}

@media (max-width: 479px){
            .portfolio-modal .close-modal {
    width: 50px;
}
}
```

Comment: Nas 6 ultimas linhas você está fazendo uma sobrescrita, media all inclui midia screen, sugiro que leia esse conteúdo do MDN falando  sobre Media Query https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/CSS_Media_queries, Cuide também da sua formatação, após abrir media você precisa utilizar {}

Comment: é que estou achando estranho, pq somente essa classe não está pegando o responsivo o resto está.

Comment: Esse código não vai funcionar mesmo, está faltando a } fechando a primeira media e {} abrindo e fechando a segunda...

Comment: estava fechado só esqueci de colocar aqui no final. Atualizei como está o codigo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O correto seria assim

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    body {
        background-color: lightgreen;
    }
}
```

Entendeu faltou o '{' depois do media, isso serve para delimitar o que faz parte da regra.

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Links auxiliares para o seu estudo.

---

Fiz um teste aqui e funcionou o código, veja:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

    <style>
    .teste {

       height: 100px;
       width: 180px;
       background-color: red;
    }

    @media (max-width: 479px){
        .teste {
            width: 50px;
        }
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
     <div class="teste"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Se não funcionar a outra coisa impactando no se css

Comment: não funcionou amigo, deu a mesma coisa

Comment: atualize o css que está na sua perguta, lembrando que não de passei uma solução e sim um exemplo de como deve ser, ok

Comment: atualizei lá... acho que está certo mas algo está fazendo não pegar.

Comment: tente assim @media (max-width: 479px) {, tire a segunda media query ela tambem pode estar te causando problemas, deixe so uma, da maneira que de mostrei.

Comment: atualizei amigo, mesmo assim não estou conseguindo.

Comment: editei minha resposta da uma conferida

Comment: Sim agora deu certo obrigado amigo, só no HTML fica meio feio, mas o importante é funcionar OBRIGADO.

Comment: Na verdade o problema era o `mediatype` que estava a ser omitido `screen`.